# Limiting code access to method call within main AppDomain (.NET)

Tags: .net, code-access-security

Is it possible in .NET to limit the permissions granted to a method call without running the code within a separate app domain?

For example, let's say I load in an assembly FooBar.dll which I know has a class called MyClass and I would like to make calls to this class within my application. This DLL could have come from anywhere or is compiled from code which could contain malicious content. Is there a way for me to restrict all code called within this DLL before loading it and impose code access security on code within the DLL? Such that all code within the DLL is restricted but running within my main root AppDomain. And has very limited access to the operating system and other functions, and cannot elevate it's own privileges and demand access to features again.

Is this possible, if so any ideas how? Or is this only possible if using an AppDomain

Comment: Keep in mind that the AppDomain was designed for this sort of problem.

Comment: I sort of realise this, but it's a real pain marshalling data back and forth across domain boundaries. Is that basically a no then ?